# Starting a script in a postinst of init.d causes script to not terminate

Tags: debian, services

I have a `postinst` script that looks like this.

However, when I start the service on the last line of the `postinst` the script hangs and doesn't enter a terminal state

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
# Source debconf library.
. /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
mkdir -p /var/www
mkdir -p /var/log/robotasarouter
rm -f /var/www/robot_configuration_interface
ln -s /usr/share/robot_configuration_interface /var/www/
pip install virtualenv
cd /var/www/robot_configuration_interface
virtualenv env
. env/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
update-rc.d robot-configuration-interface defaults 90 >/dev/null
service robot-configuration-interface start
```

Answer (score 0):

This postinst script is against the rules on so many points that you can't expect it to behave sanely in general. Most probably it hangs because its sends unexpected output to `stdout`. Read `man debconf-devel`, which explicitly forbids that.